# JQuery DataTables doesn't save the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table which uses JQuery DataTables. It's a list of items each one with an hyperlink. When the user clicks on that hyperlink they go to a separate 'detail' page. When they go back I'd like them to find the table how they found it.

This is the initialisation script for the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Setup - add a text input to the cell's headers
 document.querySelectorAll('#mainTable thead th')[1].innerHTML += '&lt;input type="text" placeholder="Search" /&gt;';
 document.querySelectorAll('#mainTable thead th')[2].innerHTML += '&lt;input type="text" placeholder="Search" /&gt;';
 document.querySelectorAll('#mainTable thead th')[3].innerHTML += '&lt;input type="text" placeholder="Search" /&gt;';
 document.querySelectorAll('#mainTable thead th')[4].innerHTML += '&lt;input type="text" placeholder="Search" /&gt;';


// DataTable

var table = $('#mainTable').DataTable( {
    colReorder: true,
    lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    retrieve: true,
    saveState: true,

  "columns": [
    { "orderable": true,
      "className": "dateSent" },
    { "orderable": false },
    { "orderable": false },
    { "orderable": false },
    { "orderable": false },
    { "orderable": false },
    ]
} );

// Apply the filter


$("#mainTable thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
    table
        .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
        });
```

It used to work earlier and the only thing I remember I changed is adding the single-column search. Even removing it, though, doesn't help. Can somone point me in the right direction?

As it is now, every time the user clicks 'back' from the detail page they'll find the table at page 1, even if they left it at page 3.

**Update**

After many unsuccessful tests I started testing on different browsers and it turns out that it is very likely to be an issue with the AdBlocker Ultimate plugin which prevents DataTables to store to the localStorage. Apologies for the poor-formulated question and for wasting your time when the issue was a stupid and un-related to DataTables itself one!

**Update II**

As I stated above, the issue was due to a ad-blocking plugin in my browser. The reproducible example which I'd provide would be the same as the one working here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html , since that's where I took my original code to begin. It'd therefore be redundant especially, as I repeat, the issue was not in the code but in the browser.

Comment: It works in the docs example https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Would a link to the website be OK?

Comment: @MrUpsidown PS: I just noticed that the localStorage is not updated when going to a new page within the table, while in the working example, of course, it is. So the stateSave is not even triggered, let alone loaded when the user goes back.

Comment: No. Read the [mcve] link. It says *Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem **in the question itself***.

Comment: Wow, negative vote! Thanks so much for your support. Really encouraging. I was preparing the example (apologies for not reading the guidelines more closely, my bad) but then I found a workaround so I won't even bother.

Comment: If you edit your question and make it appropriate, down-voters might remove their down vote. That happens. And the same goes for close-votes. A "problem" that nobody can reproduce is very unlikely to help anyone else, especially if your "solution" is a workaround that doesn't explain why it wouldn't work before, and why it works now.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining, I'll try to troubleshoot it further and try to come up with more information.

Comment: @HBMCS Voting to reopen based on your updates, but if that doesn't happen could you update your existing accepted answer with the ad blocking information? As it stands that answer doesn't give the full story.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you, I did as you asked, I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Temporary hack - not the real solution to the real problem:**

For some reason adding the old code:

```
retrieve: true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables', JSON.stringify(oData) );
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables') );
        },
```

(see [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2012-01-16)) to the table's initialisation, rather than the modern and nicer `saveState: true` does the trick, so I'm now using that.

**Real problem/solution**

The real issue here was due to an ad-blocking extension of my browser (sorry for all the fuss!). Disabling it restores the expected behaviour of DataTables, i.e. it saves the state (page number etc.) into localStorage. This wasn't always happening with the ad-blocking extension enabled.